# Apply boolean mask to last two dimensions of tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm in the process of porting a bunch of Numpy calculations over to TensorFlow. At one stage in my calculations, I use a boolean mask to extract and flatten a subset of values from a large array. The array can have many dimensions, but the boolean mask acts only on the last two dimensions. In Numpy, it looks something like this:

```
mask = np.array([
    [False, True , True , True ],
    [True , False, True , True ],
    [True , True , False, False],
    [True , True , False, False]]

large_array_masked = large_array[..., mask]
```

I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of this in TensorFlow. I tried:

```
tf.boolean_mask(large_array, mask, axis = -2)
```

That doesn't work because `tf.boolean_mask()` doesn't seem to take negative axis arguments.

As an ugly hack, I tried forcing `mask` to broadcast to the same shape as `large_array` using:

```
mask_broadcast = tf.logical_and(tf.fill(tf.shape(large_array), True), mask)
large_array_masked = tf.boolean_mask(large_array, mask_broadcast)
```

It appears that `mask_broadcast` has the shape and value that I want, but I get the error:

```
ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None
```

Presumably this happens because `large_array` is calculated from inputs and therefore its shape is not static.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I've found that in tensorflow you want good known shapes. This is because most operations are matrix multiplications and the matrices are fixed shape.

If you really want to do this you need to convert to sparse tensor and then apply `tf.sparse_retain`.

The "equivalent" I would normally use in tensorflow is to multiply the mask with the large_array to 0 out the False values (`large_array_masked = large_array * mask`). This keeps the original shape so it makes it easier to pass to dense layers, etc...

Comment: I came up with a hack to solve my narrow problem (see below), but I'm accepting your answer because it's probably more generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a hack to solve my narrow problem so I'm posting here, but I'm accepting the answer from @Sorin because it's probably more generally applicable.

To get around the fact that `tf.boolean_mask()` can only act on the initial indices, I just rolled the indices forward, applied the mask, and then rolled them back. In simplified form, it looks like this:

```
indices = tf.range(tf.rank(large_array))
large_array_rolled_forward = tf.transpose(
    large_array,
    tf.concat([indices[-2:], indices[:-2]], axis=0))
large_array_rolled_forward_masked = tf.boolean_mask(
    large_array_rolled_forward,
    mask)
new_indices = tf.range(tf.rank(large_array_rolled_forward_masked))
large_array_masked = tf.transpose(
    large_array_rolled_forward_masked,
    tf.concat([new_indices[1:], [0]], axis=0))
```